# QML text doesn't display unicode characters

Tags: html, qt, text, qml, unicode-string

I have a long string containing html contents and unicode without quotes which I am not able to display in qml. It is displayed as empty box.
`Eg: <b> DUMMY TEXT \u0096 DISPLAY </b>`  This should be displayed as DUMMY TEXT - DISPLAY.
Code: Just a simple text

```
Text{
  text: qsTr(desc)
  textFormat: Text.RichText
 }
```

How do I display unicode characters too?

Comment: Please check your translation (qsTr) output. In my PC your example text displayed right, so its smells like fonts configuration or translation file problem.

Comment: Hi. You  mean to say u got hyphen for the unicode on eg?

Comment: I guess you have to use `&#x96;` since you want html string